# how to eliminate zero with a union query

Tags: sql-server

I have table and when i query, i get

```
SELECT code
  ,year(prime_date) AS year
  ,month(prime_date) AS currentmonth
  ,0 AS lastmonth
  ,count(*) AS currentmonth_vol
  ,0 AS lastmonth_vol
FROM TableA
WHERE month(prime_date) = month(CURRENT_DATE)
  ,year(prime_date) = year(CURRENT_DATE)
GROUP BY code
  ,year
  ,month(prime_date)
  ,year(CURRENT_DATE)
```

```
code  year   currentmonth  currentmonth_vol  lastmonth    lastmonth_vol
ah    2000    4             450                0            0          
bh    2000    4             333                0            0
```

```
SELECT code
  ,year(prime_date) AS year
  ,month(prime_date) AS currentmonth
  ,0 AS lastmonth
  ,count(*) AS currentmonth_vol
  ,0 AS lastmonth_vol
FROM TableA
WHERE month(prime_date) = month(CURRENT_DATE) - 1
  ,year(prime_date) = year(CURRENT_DATE)
GROUP BY code
  ,year
  ,month(prime_date)
  ,year(CURRENT_DATE)
```

```
code  year   currentmonth  currentmonth_vol  lastmonth    lastmonth_vol
ah    2000    0               0                3            453          
bh    2000    0               0                3            673
kt    2000    0               0                3            838
```

my question is, is it possible to join the above and eliminate 0 by union query. ?

ans should be

```
code  year   currentmonth  currentmonth_vol  lastmonth    lastmonth_vol
ah    2000    4               450                3            453          
bh    2000    4               333                3            673
kt    2000    0                0                 3            838
```

Comment: Try a `UNION` of the two results then `GROUP BY` `code` and `year` and `SUM` the other columns

Answer (score 1):

Try the following, not tested:

```
SELECT
    code,
    year,
    MAX(currentmonth) AS currentmonth,
    SUM(currentmonth_vol) AS currentmonth_vol
    lastmonth,
    lastmonth_vol
FROM
    (SELECT * FROM resulta UNION SELECT * FROM resultb) AS p
GROUP BY
    code, year, lastmonth
```

Comment: please note that both query above are generated are from same table. And that table is quite big, 6 million data. In your example you mentioned as two tables ... and union in the from statement with out any where condition, it may create big volume. could you please check again. thank you.

Comment: Could you please update your question with your new constraints. I answered your question as phrased. Have you tried this?

Comment: I have solved the above using the hints you guys provided. I have done a self join and did a inner join to get the results.

Answer (score 1):

**untested**

Not a direct answer to your question.  I suggest doing it all in 1 query instead of trying to use union and "eliminate" zeros.  Side note -- lastmonth column seems a little silly, and it will be wrong (0) the way you have it written when current month is January.

This presumes CURRENT_DATE is somehow a constant.  I wrote it here as a variable set to the current date.

```
declare @CURRENT_DATE datetime = getdate()
SELECT code
  ,year(@CURRENT_DATE) AS year
  ,month(@CURRENT_DATE) AS currentmonth
  ,month(dateadd("m", -1, @CURRENT_DATE)) AS lastmonth
  ,sum(case when month(prime_date) = month(@CURRENT_DATE) then 1 else 0 end) AS currentmonth_vol
  ,sum(case when month(prime_date) = month(@CURRENT_DATE) then 0 else 1 end) AS lastmonth_vol
FROM TableA
WHERE prime_date >= datefromparts(year(dateadd("m", -1, @CURRENT_DATE)), month(dateadd("m", -1, @CURRENT_DATE)), 1)
    and prime_date < datefromparts(year(dateadd("m", 1, @CURRENT_DATE)), month(dateadd("m", 1, @CURRENT_DATE)), 1)
GROUP BY code
```